# SQL Server change management

Tags: sql, sql-server, sqltools

Does anybody know of a good change management tool for SQL Server?

We would like to use it to migrate our existing clients database to newer version via an api.

Answer (score 2):

I work as a product manager at Red Gate. We have the [SQL Comparison SDK](https://www.red-gate.com/products/sql-development/sql-comparison-sdk/), which provides access to an API that you can use to compare two schemas and generate a change script to apply to the target. However, this has limitations if complex data migrations are required as part of the change.

We're working on improving this in the next release. We're adding a new feature, SQL Migrations, that will allow you to specify your own custom scripts for 'complex' changes. The comparison and synchronization tool, SQL Compare, will work in conjunction with SQL Source Control to provide this functionality. If you're interested, there's an [early access program](http://www.red-gate.com/MessageBoard/viewtopic.php?t=12970). We're hoping to get a beta release out in September 2011.

Answer (score 1):

I found a tool that will do the work for me DB Ghost from http://www.innovartis.co.uk/

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

there is no 100% solution out there...

Bute in my experience the tools from redgate are rather good at this - see http://www.red-gate.com/products/sql-development/sql-developer-bundle/ and esp. http://www.red-gate.com/products/sql-development/sql-packager/

Comment: Yep, Reg Gate tools are the best, but I would not call them a "good change management tool" in the context of state of the art source control.

Comment: database tools are not even near the state of the art source control... database tools are still in "baby stage" in this regard... if one keeps that in mind they do a good job, esp. in comparison to built-in options (which are mostly none)

Answer (score 0):

Not really - not out of the box. The best and most flexible approach would be to create change scripts for all your changes to the database, and then include those into your regular deployment, and run them, either on your own, or using a tool such as [SSW SQL Deploy](http://www.ssw.com.au/ssw/SQLDeploy/) (which can be run as a stand-alone command line tool, a stand-alone wizard, or from your app through a .NET interface).

The .NET Entity Framework team has started an initiative called [EF Code-First Migrations](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/efdesign/archive/2010/10/22/code-first-database-evolution-aka-migrations.aspx) which aims at easing this database upgrade scenario - this is very new and very much still work in progress, but it looks quite promising, if you're using the code-first approach with Entity Framework.

Comment: are you advocating the use of Entity Framework?  (He said trying to keep a straight face).

Comment: @Hogan: it's definitely worth a look - yes!

Answer (score 0):

We at a government ministry, are using [Kal Admin](http://www.KalromSystems.com), and like it a lot . 
We are using it for Change Management, source control aka version control and Compare. I am not sure but I think it's not expensive.